# How to override Foundation's display:inherit property for visibility classes?

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation, css

I'm using Foundation in a mobile first project where many elements are hidden based on the browser size, and I'm running into some trouble using Foundation's visibility classes like `.show-for-small-only` as Foundation applies

`display: inherit !important;`

to any element which uses these visibility classes. (For example, see line 5808)...

```
.show-for-small-only {
    display:inherit !important;
}
```

This is causing me issues. Say have an element that I want to `.show-for-small-only`:

```
<div class="someElem show-for-small-only">
    <!-- Content -->
</div>
```

Yet I want this element, when shown, to be formatted as a `display:inline-block` element. Due to Foundation's use of `!important`, the div is forced to assume it's default display state of `block`.

Is there any workaround to this, short of declaring my styling as `!important` too? (I don't want to have to do that though)...

Answer (score 1):

I agree, using `!important` always feels gross.

Precedence in CSS is given to the element furthest down the tree so to override the Foundation `!important` property, just target an element further down the tree, like so:

```
<div class="show-for-small-only">
 <div class="someElm">

  <!-- your content here -->

 </div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS

```
.someElm {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's a [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/Ewa62fDT9UNkGVhInv8h/preview) for kicks (just remember the items wont show up unless the screen is small).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite `inportant` just declare it again after the first declaration

```css
.show-for-small-only {
  display:inherit !important;
}
.show-for-small-only {
  display: inline-block!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="someElem show-for-small-only">
  Content 
</div>
```

[image]